# How to create PayPal payment requests via python

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am looking for a way to create payment requests via a Python desktop application. Just found out about the PayPal REST SDK but it seems not to provide a way to create standard requests like the ones every personal user can create in the webinterface. Is there another way to create a request and track the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple money requests can only be sent via the web interface, but invoices can be created and sent programmatically via [the Invoicing API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/).